# Cached this, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I often see the code like this one:

```
$('.element').on('click', function(event) {
  var element = this;

  // somecode that uses "element"
});
```

Is there any reason to cache `this`?

Comment: `this` changes based on scope. So you may want to reference the original at some point.

Comment: what if there's no scope changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is necessary if the code contains a closure that needs to access `this`. `this` is not a local variable, so it will not be captured in the closure, you need to bind a local variable for that purpose.

You also need it if the code contains a loop using a function like `$.each()`, and the body of the loop needs to refer to the element. These functions rebind `this` in the body to the current iteration object.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people set a reference to `this` if they need to reference it in another scope of code. For example:

```
$('.element').on('click', function(event) {
  var element = this;

  // somecode that users "element"
  function foo() {
      //$(this).text() WONT Work!
      alert($(element).text()); //references the element that was clicked
  }
});
```

Comment: Object literal declaration does not change the `this` binding. Functions do.

Comment: You could've used `{ text: function() { return $(this).text(); } }` in the object literal example but well, either way the example is more correct now. Just fix the "this references foo" part which you left behind. `=]`

Comment: I mean, the comment "this references foo" from your first example does not apply to your new example. The `this` binding for a `foo()` invocation would be `window` (or `null` in strict mode).

Answer (score 1):

Once you are inside a function or loop, `this` might refer to an object within that function. Therefor explicity assigning the element allows you to always access it, independent of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not a jQuery element, wrap it in `$(this)`.

Caching is good because it stores the element, and it doesn't take up memory or processing time trying to re-find the element. However, `this` changes on scope so you might not want to cache that one.